# Primefaces & Radiobutton not updating Bean Value

Tags: primefaces

My goal is to use ajax in order to activate/deactivate menus based on the values of a radio button.
My problem is that the radio button with id="selectCategoryType" does not update the value in the Bean (catWordGuiBean.addCategoryType) - since I do not have a complex object but a string I do not need a custom converter.

Here is my code:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" 
    >
    <h:head>
        <link rel="shortcut icon"
            href="http://localhost:8080/DeviceCommander/resources/images/favicon.ico" />
        <title>
            <h:outputText value=" Pronounciator "/>
        </title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <p:layout fullPage="true">
            
            <p:layoutUnit id="up" position="north" header="" resizable="true" closable="false" collapsible="true">
                <h:form id="header">
                    <p:panelGrid columns="6" layout="grid" cellspacing="20" styleClass="ui-noborder">
                        <h:graphicImage value="resources/images/pronuncia.jpg" height="70" width="120" />
                        <h:outputText value=" #{display.date}: " /> 
                        <h:outputText id="now" value="#{timeBean.now}" />   
                        <p:poll interval="1" listener="#{timeBean.updateDate}" update="now" />
                        <h:outputText value=" #{display.theme}: " />
                        <p:themeSwitcher effectSpeed="normal" effect="fade" style="width:165px" id="defaultSwitcher" value="#{themeSwitcherBean.theme}">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel=" #{display.select} #{display.theme} " itemValue="" />
                            <f:selectItems value=" #{themeSwitcherBean.themes} " />
                            <p:ajax global="false" listener="#{themeSwitcherBean.saveTheme}" />
                        </p:themeSwitcher>
                    </p:panelGrid>
                </h:form>   
            </p:layoutUnit>
            <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                <p:panelGrid styleClass="ui-noborder">
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column colspan="1">
                            <p:panelGrid>
                                <h:form id="db">
                                    <p:row>
                                        <p:column colspan="4">
                                            <h3>
                                                <h:outputText value=" ADD: " />
                                            </h3>
                                        </p:column>             
                                    </p:row>
                                    <p:row>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <h:outputText for="selectCategoryType" value=" Category: " />
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column colspan="3">
                                            <p:selectOneRadio id="selectCategoryType" value="#{catWordGuiBean.addCategoryType}" >
                                                <p:ajax event="click" update="addOldCategory" listener="#{catWordGuiBean.handleCategorySelection}" />
                                                <f:selectItems value="#{catWordGuiBean.addCategoryTypes}" var="addCategoryType" itemLabel="#{addCategoryType}" itemValue="#{addCategoryType}"/>
                                            </p:selectOneRadio>
                                        </p:column>
                                    </p:row>
                                    <p:row>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <h:outputText value=" Old Category: " />
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column colspan="3">
                                            <p:selectOneMenu id="addOldCategory" value="" disabled="#{catWordGuiBean.disabledOldCategoryGui}">
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="AH" itemValue="AH" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="UH" itemValue="UH" />
                                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                                        </p:column>
                                    </p:row>
                                    <p:row>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <h:outputText value=" New Category: " />
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <p:inputTextarea id="addNewCategoryName" rows="1" cols="4" maxlength="4" autoResize="false" value="#{catWordGuiBean.newCategoryName}" disabled="#{catWordGuiBean.disabledNewCategoryGui}"/>
                                        </p:column>
                                         <p:column>
                                            <h:outputText value=" IPA: "/> 
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <p:inputTextarea id="addNewIpa" rows="1" cols="3" maxlength="3" autoResize="false" value="#{catWordGuiBean.newIpa}" disabled="#{catWordGuiBean.disabledNewCategoryGui}"/>
                                        </p:column>
                                    </p:row>
                                    <p:row>                                 
                                        <p:column>
                                            <h:outputText value=" Word: "/> 
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column colspan="3">
                                            <p:inputText id="addNewWord"/>
                                        </p:column>
                                    </p:row>
                                    <p:row>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <h:outputText value=" Submit: "/> 
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column colspan="3">
                                            <p:commandButton id="addCategoryAndWord" value="Add" />
                                        </p:column>
                                    </p:row>
                                    <p:row>
                                        <p:column colspan="4">
                                            <h3>
                                                <h:outputText value=" DELETE: "/>
                                            </h3>
                                        </p:column>
                                    </p:row>
                                    <p:row>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <h:outputText value=" Category: "/> 
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column colspan="2">
                                            <p:selectOneMenu id="deleteOldCategory" value="" >
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="AH" itemValue="AH" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="UH" itemValue="UH" />
                                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <p:commandButton id="deleteCategory" value="Delete" />
                                        </p:column>
                                    </p:row>
                                    <p:row>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <h:outputText value=" Word: "/> 
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column colspan="2">
                                            <p:selectOneMenu id="deleteOldWord" value="" >
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="AH" itemValue="AH" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="UH" itemValue="UH" />
                                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <p:commandButton id="deleteWord" value="Delete" />
                                        </p:column>
                                    </p:row>
                                </h:form>   
                            </p:panelGrid>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column colspan="4">
                            <p:panelGrid>
                                <h:form id="randomizer">
                                    <p:row>
                                        <p:column>                                      
                                            <h3>
                                                <h:outputText value=" Select Categories: "/>
                                            </h3>
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column colspan="2">
                                            <p:selectOneMenu id="selectWordCategories" value="" >
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" itemValue="" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="AH" itemValue="Xbox One" />
                                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="UH" itemValue="PS4" />
                                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                                        </p:column>
                                    </p:row>
                                    <p:row>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <p:commandButton id="wordGenerator" value="Generate Word" />
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <p:commandButton id="categoryFinder" value="Show Word Category" />
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <h3>
                                                <h:outputText value=" Show Category in: "/>
                                            </h3>
                                            <p:knob value="{wordRandomizerBean.seconds}">  
                                                <p:ajax listener="#{wordRandomizerBean.knobChange}"/>  
                                            </p:knob>
                                        </p:column>
                                    </p:row>
                                    <p:row>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <h1>
                                                <h:outputText value=" Word: "/> 
                                            </h1>
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column colspan="2">
                                            <h1>
                                                <h:outputText value=" #{wordRandomizerBean.randomWord} "/> 
                                            </h1>
                                        </p:column>
                                    </p:row>
                                    <p:row>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <h1>
                                                <h:outputText value=" Category: "/> 
                                            </h1>
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <h1>
                                                <h:outputText value=" IPA: "/> 
                                            </h1>
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <h1>
                                                <h:outputText value=" Category: "/> 
                                            </h1>
                                        </p:column>
                                    </p:row>
                                </h:form>   
                            </p:panelGrid>                              
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                </p:panelGrid>      
            </p:layoutUnit>
        </p:layout>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

And the Bean:

```java
package com.linknet.beans;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent;

@ManagedBean(name = "catWordGuiBean")
@ViewScoped
public class CategoryWordManagementBean {
    public CategoryWordManagementBean() {
        this.disabledNewCategoryGui = true;
        this.disabledOldCategoryGui = true;
        this.addCategoryType = "";
    }
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        addCategoryTypes = new ArrayList<String>();
        addCategoryTypes.add("New");
        addCategoryTypes.add("Old");
    }

    
    public void enableNewCategory() {
        this.disabledNewCategoryGui = false;
    }
    public void disableNewCategory() {
        this.disabledNewCategoryGui = true;
    }
    public void enableOldCategory() {
        this.disabledOldCategoryGui = false;
    }
    public void disableOldCategory() {
        this.disabledOldCategoryGui = true;
    }
    public void handleCategorySelection(AjaxBehaviorEvent  e) {
        System.out.println("Test 1");
        System.out.println(addCategoryType);
    }
    

    public boolean isDisabledNewCategoryGui() {
        return this.disabledNewCategoryGui;
    }
    public void setDisabledNewCategoryGui(boolean disabledNewCategoryGui) {
        this.disabledNewCategoryGui = disabledNewCategoryGui;
    }
    public boolean isDisabledOldCategoryGui() {
        return disabledOldCategoryGui;
    }
    public void setDisabledOldCategoryGui(boolean disabledOldCategoryGui) {
        this.disabledOldCategoryGui = disabledOldCategoryGui;
    }
    public String getAddCategoryType() {
        return addCategoryType;
    }
    public void setAddCategoryType(String addCategoryType) {
        this.addCategoryType = addCategoryType;
    }
    
    public String getNewCategoryName() {
        return newCategoryName;
    }
    public void setNewCategoryName(String newCategoryName) {
        this.newCategoryName = newCategoryName;
    }
    public String getNewIpa() {
        return newIpa;
    }
    public void setNewIpa(String newIpa) {
        this.newIpa = newIpa;
    }
    private boolean disabledNewCategoryGui;
    private boolean disabledOldCategoryGui;
    
    private List<String> addCategoryTypes;  
    public List<String> getAddCategoryTypes() {
        return addCategoryTypes;
    }
    public void setAddCategoryTypes(List<String> addCategoryTypes) {
        this.addCategoryTypes = addCategoryTypes;
    }
    private String addCategoryType;
    private String newCategoryName;
    private String newIpa;
}
```

Where is my mistake?

I appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, edit you question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

change your ajax event from `click` to `change` so the `listener` get execute after the value of `catWordGuiBean.addCategoryType` is updated

```
<p:ajax event="change" update="addOldCategory" listener="#{catWordGuiBean.handleCategorySelection}" />
```